# Flex Browser Automation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, browser, automation

I'm trying to create a Flex application that automates a web browser to perform certain tasks.  I would use the application to login to a site, parse data out of the HTML, and send it to a jsp page for processing.

I currently have an application written in WPF that does that exact thing, but it needs to be ported to flex.  Any known ways to do this easily?

Answer (score 1):

Have the server code of your flex app talk to your wpf app to control the browser on the server. You won't be able to take control of the users browser with flex (or any other web application language for that matter).

Comment: I would agree with Byron.  This seems like a task much more suited for a server side language.  Technically you could accomplish this with AIR as long as your application doesn't require that it be in a browser.